# SSLError: SSL validation failed when loading a file to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, automation

I am using below code to place a csv file to S3 bucket but I get SSL Error as mentioned below. Can anyone please advise what can I do to fix this. Thanks.

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
transfer.upload_file('C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Workbook.csv', 'bucketname', 'folder in s3')
```

Error:
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or VPN?

Comment: I tried both being on VPN and without it. But both ways it gives the same SSL error.